# Invert Scrolling with Asus Smart Gesture for RoG computer

Tags: windows-8.1, touchpad

I saw a conversation on here a while back, but it didn't answer my question.  I have a pretty spiffy computer all things considered, running WIN 8.1 (I'm still afraid to jump into Win10).  But my touchpad doesn't give an option for "inverted scrolling" (which would simulate dragging a screen down or up, as opposed to "swiping up to go up, down to go down".

Here's an image of the ASUS Smart Gesture control panel, but there isn't an option for more options, where I'd expect to find the option!  Anyone know a solution for this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have an **old** version of Smart Gesture.

The latest version allows you to invert the scroll. You can find v4.0.12 [here](https://ivanrf.com/en/latest-asus-drivers-for-windows-10/#smart-gesture).